# Replacing string characters with characters that are contained within each other

Tags: python, replace

Alright here is the bit in question.

```
if any(char in word for char in ["a", "ā", "e", "ē", "i", "ī", "u", "ū", "o", "ai", "ei", "ui"]):
for ch in ["a", "ā", "e", "ē", "i", "ī", "u", "ū", "o", "ai", "ei", "ui"]:
    if ch in word:
       word = word.replace(ch, ch + "p" + ch)
```

This might seem a bit weird but its for a translator for Latvian umm.. slang.
    I know finding the vowels could probably be done much more efficiently but my problem is that i want it to not take, for example, the "i" in "ei" if the ei is there. right now it takes for example *"aiza"* and gives *"apaipaipizapa"* instead of the preferred *"aipaizapa"*. Hope this hasn't been asked too many times, English is not my native so i didn't know how to formulate an effective search term.
    Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I am afraid i worded my issue quite poorly. what i need is 
So, here is an **example**.

```
list = ["a", "b", "ay", "by"] 
state = input("Type a, b, ay or by")
for char in list
    if char in state
        state = state.replace(char, k)
print state
```

So now, if the input is **by** or **ay** it will give **kk** but I need it to give out a single **k**. How do i achieve Python 3 ignoring the smaller value if it is a part of the bigger one?

Comment: yeah but when i replace the long ones and it runs through the small ones it still finds them in the new "eipei"s or whatever. i need a way to say do not replace if the i is inside ei.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you break that bit of code down a bit so its a bit more understandable? I'm sorry but i am a bit of a newbie at coding, especially python.

Comment: I think I understood what you wanted. Regex will take care of that, as two "matches" within a string will not overlap, and all the characters are replaced in one go, so it can not happen that the "result" of one replacement is replaced again.

Answer (score 2):

You can join those characters to a regular expression using `|`. Make sure to sort the multi-char parts first, so they are preferred in the match (i.e. it matches `ai` instead of `a` and then `i`). Then use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a callback function:

```
>>> chars = ["a", "ā", "e", "ē", "i", "ī", "u", "ū", "o", "ai", "ei", "ui"] 
>>> s = "aiza"
>>> p = "|".join(sorted(chars, key=len, reverse=True))
>>> print(p)
ā|ē|ī|ū|ai|ei|ui|a|e|i|u|o
>>> re.sub(p, lambda m: "{0}p{0}".format(m.group()), s)
'aipaizapa'
```

Regular expression matches are non-overlapping, and since it replaces all the characters at once, and one one after the other, characters that are part of other characters will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not python3, but from what I understood from your second example, try this:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "ay", "by"] 
state = input("Type a, b, ay or by: ")

for char in state:
    if char in list1:
        print("k")
        break
```